# How should I connect my new light switches?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle, light

I have 2 bedrooms in which I am trying to swap the old light switches out with new switches. After removing covers, found the old switches had 2 black wires connected to the two terminals, and 2 white wires connected by a wire nut - separately from the switch.

When I installed the new switch in the same configuration, the light wouldn't work.

What should I do to identify & fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Please only ask one question at a time; click "Ask Question" in the upper right to create a new question for your second part

Comment: Do you mean that both terminals of the switch have black wires on them and then there are two white wires that are connected via a wire nut?

Comment: Is this a 4 terminal switch? (DPST) I haven't seen one in a few years but it was one way to have 2 separate circuits on a single switch. The blacks on top each side and the whites on the bottom each side forming 2 switch loops. If this is the case don't combine them.

Comment: Aaron, yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ed Beal, it was a standard single pole light switch that I want to switch out for a single pole 'paddle' switch. I will add pictures of wiring and switches as soon as I am able.

Comment: I'm not sure what Andrew's concern is, exactly, but I think his wording has some of you confused. The whites are connected to each other, not the switch, as I interpret it.

Comment: isherwood, that's correct. My issue is that when I installed the new switch in the same configuration, the light fixture wouldn't work.

Comment: You might've mentioned that in your question. There's something else going wrong, then. Update your post with a photo or a link to the switch's product page.

Comment: Noted, isherwood - see updated post... Will add photos in the next couple of hours. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Well, you've wired it correctly from what I can tell. Things to check: 1. Reset circuit breaker. 2. Try a different light bulb. 3. Faulty switch? (put the old one back in and see if everything still works).

Comment: I guess I just didn't have good contact on a terminal, bc after resetting breaker, disconnecting and reconnecting the new switch, it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is very typical in cases where power comes into the switch box (as opposed to the light box). The hot leg is switched.

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/light-switch-wiring-diagrams.html)</sub>

Simply move the blacks to your new switch in either terminal configuration. Be sure to use clean, solid loops and wrap them clockwise. Leave the whites alone.

Comment: This is the closest diagram to my situation that i've seen. Removing the ground wiring completely, would make it 100% accurate to the wiring that i'm dealing with.

Comment: ishewood, does not having any ground wiring affect your instruction or the outcome?

Comment: No. I started writing about that and decided to avoid the complication. Just ignore the green wires in the diagram.

Comment: Got it. Is it possible/necessary to ground - by adding ground wire from grounding terminal on the switch to the box?

Comment: Only if the box is grounded. If there's no grounded conductor, and there's no metal conduit, there's no ground path.

Comment: Is the new switch a simple mechanical switch with only two contact screws? That type only requires connecting two wires, usually black, line hot and switched hot out to the light fixture or switched receptacle.  But some new single pole switches require, in addition, a neutral connection (white) because they are powered devices.

Comment: The new switch only had two contacts, and I have gotten it to work following the diagram above.